# Using two different where clauses

Tags: t-sql, if-statement, case, where-clause, apply

I would like to know how to use a different `WHERE` clause based on a `CASE` or `IF`. I'd prefer a `CASE`, as the rest of the statement is complex, and I don't like the idea of that complexity being in two places with only a minor difference. However, I know cases are only used for values. I've replicated a simple version of my issue below.

Essentially, I have three tables. The first contains the master information (MasterTable). The second contains a one-to-many relationship belonging to the master table (Table1). The third is a list of selectors indicating which of the records in Table1 are to be used in this instance. I want the most recent record of Table2 to drive what is selected from Table1, with precedence given to SubID over OrderNum.

MasterTable | MasterID, OtherInfo

Table1 | T1UniqueId, MasterID, SubID, Text, OrderNum

Table2 | T2UniqueId, MasterID, SubID, OrderNum, Date

```
SELECT MasterID, OtherInfo, SubID
FROM MasterTable
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 SubID FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.MasterID=MasterTable.MasterID
    CASE
        WHEN 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 SubID FROM Table2 
            WHERE Table2.MasterID=MasterTable.MasterID 
            ORDER BY Date DESC
        ) Is NULL
        THEN Table1.OrderNum=
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 OrderNum 
                FROM Table2
                WHERE Table2.MasterId=MasterTable.MasterId
                ORDER BY Date DESC
            )
        ELSE Table1.SubId=
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 SubId
                FROM Table2
                WHERE Table2.MasterId=MasterTable.MasterId
                ORDER BY Date DESC
            )
    END

) SubData
```

Comment: If this would work you would still need an additional `AND` before the `CASE` in your `WHERE`-clause, but unfortunately `CASE` cannot be used that way, it simply just outputs values from `THEN` and `ELSE` to the embedding expression; you cannot use it to output a condition.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Thanks. I did know that bit, but I'm not sure how to correct it to do what I'm wanting. I was using the case to illustrate more than suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick rewrite of this would result in the following:

```
IF ((SELECT TOP 1 SubID FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.MasterID=MasterTable.MasterID ORDER BY Date DESC) IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT
            MasterID, OtherInfo, SubID
        FROM MasterTable
        OUTER APPLY(
            SELECT TOP 1 SubID FROM Table1
            WHERE
                Table1.MasterID=MasterTable.MasterID
                AND Table1.OrderNum =
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 OrderNum 
                    FROM Table2
                    WHERE Table2.MasterId=MasterTable.MasterId
                    ORDER BY Date DESC
                )
        ) SubData
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT
            MasterID, OtherInfo, SubID
        FROM MasterTable
        OUTER APPLY(
            SELECT TOP 1 SubID FROM Table1
            WHERE
                Table1.MasterID=MasterTable.MasterID
                AND Table1.SubId=
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 SubId
                    FROM Table2
                    WHERE Table2.MasterId=MasterTable.MasterId
                    ORDER BY Date DESC
                )
        ) SubData
END
```

But as you noted that makes it look ugly, because you now have that complexity in two places...

I guess you could also formulate it this way (untested, but this should keep your complex logic in one place):

```
SELECT
        MasterID, OtherInfo, SubID
    FROM MasterTable
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT TOP 1 SubID FROM Table1
        WHERE Table1.MasterID=MasterTable.MasterID
        AND
        (
            (
                (
                    SELECT
                            TOP 1 SubID
                        FROM Table2 
                        WHERE Table2.MasterID=MasterTable.MasterID 
                        ORDER BY Date DESC
                ) IS NULL
                AND
                Table1.OrderNum =
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 OrderNum 
                    FROM Table2
                    WHERE Table2.MasterId=MasterTable.MasterId
                    ORDER BY Date DESC
                )
            )
            OR
            (
                Table1.SubId =
                (
                    SELECT
                            TOP 1 SubId
                        FROM Table2
                        WHERE Table2.MasterId=MasterTable.MasterId
                        ORDER BY Date DESC
                )
            )
        )
    ) SubData
```

Answer (score 0):

If SubID and OrderNum in Table1 and Table2 are the same you can utilize simple query with nested select statement:

```
select m.MasterID, m.OtherInfo, (
  select top 1 coalesce(t2.SubID, t2.OrderNum) from Table2 t2
  where t2.MasterID = m.MasterID order by date desc
) as SubID
from MasterTable m;
```

Comment: ordernum and subid are different. The subID is a  digit number while the ordernum indicates placement in a list. So, the order may be 1,2,3 while the subids are 000111,000222,000333. I'd like to select based on subid because there could be multiple ordered sets per masterid.

Comment: By my add I meant that Table1.SubID = Table2.SubID and Table1.OrderNum = Table2.OrderNum. If it applies, please give the query above a try

Comment: This doesn't get the desired answer from my data. I don't need to return the subId or OrderNum. I need to return what it matches to in table1.